# Android Firebase - Remove uploaded image from Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am developing a feature to remove uploaded files. I can currently remove the reference within Cloud Firestore but I am unable to remove it from Storage. The code bellow should remove from Storage but it does not work

```
    private void deleteImage(String id, final int position, String fileUrl) {

    StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

    // Create a reference to the file to delete
    StorageReference fileRef = storageRef.child(fileUrl);

    // Delete the file
    fileRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            // File deleted successfully
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
        }
    });
}
```

The error message is "No auth token for request. StorageException has occurred. Object does not exist at location. HttpResult: 404". I thought that the problem was related with my fileUrl field but I'm not sure. The fileUrl is the download image url, for example, if I copy and paste the url on web browser I can see the image. Why is not working?

Comment: `The fileUrl is the download image url,` That is an url that delivers a html page. Looks not suitable as reference to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @blackapps commented, the download url that I was using was not suitable as reference to a file so I changed the value of fileUrl parameter to *"filename.file_extension"*. The code still the same, i only changed the parameter value.